# Angular I don't call a function with (load)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want the function to work when the div is opened, but it doesn't work.

html:

```
<div class="row table-dark table-bordered">
  <div class="col-xl-12" (click)="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed;">
     Click Me!
   <ng-container *ngIf="isCollapsed;">
   <div class="col-xl-12" (load)="test()" id="test"></div>
       Open
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

function

```
test() {
   console.log("is work");
   const firstRow = document.createElement('div');
   firstRow.innerText = 'Eureka';
   firstRow.style.color = 'red';
   document.getElementById('test').appendChild(firstRow);
}
```

live example:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/focused-mendeleev-t7y4h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing as `(load)` in angular. Try

```
<div class="row table-dark table-bordered">
  <div class="col-xl-12" (click)="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed;">
     Click Me!   
  </div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="isCollapsed;">
    <div class="col-xl-12" (click)="test()" id="test">Open</div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

The problem with your code is that you have `(click)="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed;"` over parent `div`, so the `test()` was not working even if you change `load` to `click` . So I have moved it out as a separate div.

[Here is working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kjxsm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: > I want the function to work when the div is opened < -
Don't think he means when the div is clicked.

Comment: @pascalpuetz : You have a point. I have posted and asked the user to answer. Your answer provided another approach. So I didnt go that path. IMHO, The question is missing more description. Cheers :)

Comment: True, the question can be interpreted your way as well - and it will def. be helpful to users stumbling upon this question. Cheers! :)

Comment: @pascalpuetz : Yep

Answer (score 1):

You already have an event that is firing that does exactly what you need: The click that "opens" the div. Instead of only setting the `isCollapsed` variable in the template, you can just call the function there like this:

*template*

```
<div class="row table-dark table-bordered">
  <div class="col-xl-12" (click)="toggleOpenMyDiv()">
     Click Me!
     <ng-container *ngIf="isCollapsed;">
       <div class="col-xl-12" id="test"></div>
       Open
     </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

*component.ts*

```
// Call this method to open/close your div
toggleOpenMyDiv() { 
   this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed; // set the variable
   if (this.isCollapsed) {
      this.test(); // Then call test
   }
}

test() {
   console.log("is work");

   // You should not do the following lines in angular (it works but is a very bad practice!)
   const firstRow = document.createElement('div');
   firstRow.innerText = 'Eureka';
   firstRow.style.color = 'red';
   document.getElementById('test').appendChild(firstRow);
}
```

Additionally, I strongly suggest not creating HTML Elements manually like you are trying to do in your `test()` method. You can just let angular do that for you by using Bindings in your HTML.

If you were, for example, trying to add rows whenever it is opened:

*template*

```
<div class="row table-dark table-bordered">
  <div class="col-xl-12" (click)="toggleOpenMyDiv()">
     Click Me!
     <ng-container *ngIf="isCollapsed;">
       <div class="col-xl-12" id="test">

          <!-- The template for each row, angular will update this for you based on the "rows" variable -->
          <div *ngFor="let row of rows" [style.color]="row.color">{{row.text}}</div>

       </div>
       Open
     </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

*component.ts*

```
rows = []; // Every row that should be iterated over in the template

// Call this method to open/close your div
toggleOpenMyDiv() { 
   this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed; // set the variable
   if (this.isCollapsed) {
      this.test(); // Then call test
   }
}

test() {
   console.log("is work");
   // Add a row to the array, angular will take care of updating the template, just don't mutate the array but create a new one with the modifications
   this.rows = [...this.rows, {color: 'red', text: 'Eureka'}];
}
```

Here a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iw64pz).